# Scraping the movie gross for a list using BeautifulSoup (Python)

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I started coding in Python (3). I would like to extract some data related to movies, here is the [list link](https://www.imdb.com/search/title?title_type=feature&release_date=1950-01-01,2015-12-31&user_rating=6.0,10.0&num_votes=30000,&count=250)

I already scraped the data related to the number of votes:

```
first_votes = first_movie.find('span', attrs = {'name':'nv'})
first_votes

first_votes['data-value']
```

Which gives me exactly the number of times the movie has been rated by users.

But when I try to scrape the gross amount, I do not really know how to make the code concentrate on the gross since both the gross and the number of votes have the same construction:

[This is what the DevTool shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Sm7c.png)

Does anyone of you know how to solve this? Sorry if I didn't provide any additional information, but I am new. If you require some information, I would be happy to provide them.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `findAll` method to get a list of all of the elements that match your criteria and then you can select the second element in the list, e.g.:

```
first_votes = first_movie.findAll('span', attrs = {'name':'nv'})[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for `votes` and `gross`

```
votes = first_movie.find_all('span', attrs = {'name':'nv'})[0]['data-value']
gross = first_movie.find_all('span', attrs = {'name':'nv'})[1]['data-value']
```

Or in a single line

```
votes, gross = [item['data-value'] for item in first_movie.find_all('span', attrs = {'name':'nv'})]
```